# How can I get share data with hello.js?

Tags: facebook, hello.js

I'm able to log in with `hello.js` as well as get the user data (`/me`) and albums (`/me/albums`), but I haven't data from the `/share` endpoint.

Example:

```
hello.init({
  facebook : 'SECRET'
}, {scope: 'friends,photos' });


hello.on('auth.login', function(auth){

  hello( auth.network ).api( '/me' ).then( function(r){
    console.log("User data is: ");
    console.log(r);
  });

  hello( auth.network ).api( '/me/share' ).then( function(r){
    console.log("Share data is: ");
    console.log(r);
  },function(e){
    console.log("ERROR: "+e);
  });
});
```

This results in:

```
User data is: 
Object {first_name: "Lucy"} (edited to save space)
Share data is: 
Object {data: Array[0]}
```

So I was able to successfully log in with `hello.js`, but not to access the share data. Is there something I'm missing in my code? Do I need to update permissions somewhere?

[FB says](https://www.facebook.com/help/145506622264765) that asking for the public profile only makes the following available:

- Your name, user id, username, profile picture, gender and network in order to identify you
- Your age range, language and country in order to personalize the experience

So I'd expect that I'd need to ask permissions to view a user's status. But there doesn't seem to be anything in the [`hello.js` permissions docs](http://adodson.com/hello.js/#scope) to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook needs to whitelist your application before you can retrieve me/status or me/feed results.